# How do I assign a new object to both current_user and a has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Score` that belongs_to `Client` - and `Client` has_one `Score`.

I also want to assign the `Score` to `User` on creation. So every time a `current_user` creates a score for a particular client, I want the `current_user.id` to be stored with that `Score` record.

What is the best way to do that?

I was thinking that an elegant way might be a `Score belongs_to User, :through Client` but that can't work.

So I am assuming the best way is to just add `user_id` to the `Score` model, and do it like that.

But then how do I assign the `user_id` in the `Score#create`?

This is how my create action looks:

```
def create
    @score = current_user.scores.new(params[:score])

respond_to do |format|
  if @score.save
    format.html { redirect_to @score, notice: 'Score was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @score, status: :created, location: @score }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @score.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This automatically assigns the current score to the `client_id` that is in the `params[:score]` hash - but it doesn't do the same for `user_id`.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have `Score.belongs_to :user`, and the accompanying `user_id` column in the `scores` table :

```
def create
  @score = Score.new(params[:score])
  @score.user = current_user

  ...
end
```

Let me know if you need more explanation, but I feel that the code is pretty clear.

**Edit** Or: Instead of `current_user.scores.new`, use `current_user.scores.build(params[:score])`, and make sure you have `User.has_many :scores`

Comment: Shouldn't `@score = current_user.scores.new(params[:score])` do that? Why is it different?

Comment: If it shouldn't, what's the point of doing it the way I have - or is there no point to doing it like that?

Comment: `current_user.scores` returns an instance of Array (or `ActiveRecord::Relation` depending on how the association is setup) so you'll get an error. You can use the Rails helper, `current_user.scores.build(params[:score])` which will do what you're looking for, but I find it more clear to do it the way I specified (they're basically the same though).